# Is $A$ is small on bounded functions, is there a large subdomain on which $A$ is small?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Let $A$ be a symmetric linear operator of norm $\leq 1$ on the space of functions $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$, where $S$ is a set with $N$ elements. Define the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ by letting $\{x\}$ have measure $1/N$ for each $x\in S$.

Assume that, for every function $f$ such that $|f|_2=1$ and $|f|_\infty\leq K$, we have $|\langle f,A f\rangle|\leq \alpha$.

Does it follow that there must be a $Y\subset S$ of measure $O(1/K)$ (say) such that, for $X = S\setminus Y$ and any $f:S\to \mathbb{R}$ with $|f|_2=1$, $$|\langle f|_X, A(f|_X)\rangle|\leq 10 \alpha,$$ say?

Comment: Why doesn't this hold just by homoeneity for $Y=\emptyset $?  And how do you define $A (f|_X) $? Do you put the restriction as $0$ outside $X $?

Comment: I'm not sure how homogeneity would be enough - $A$ could have eigenfunctions with enormous peaks. Sure, define $A(f|_X)$ that way if you wish -- it doesn't matter, since you are going to take the inner product with $f|_X$.

Comment: I must misunderstand something. For $t=K/|f|_\infty$ one has $|tf|_\infty\le K$ and hence $$\langle f, A(f)\rangle= t^{-2} \langle tf, A(tf)\rangle \le t^{-2}\alpha |tf|_2=\alpha|f|_2.$$

Comment: Yes, I stated the question wrongly. Just fixed it. Thanks!